# Is there a way to set a timer with a lambda function that I can start and stop from my front end?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to set a timer for a user that counts every hour and minute from when they start the timer (logging in / submitting a button) to when they stop the timer (log out). I'm thinking I could use my dynamodb user table to keep the current hour from timer start and the current hour from timer end and write my own logic on it to tally up the hours. I feel this method is inefficient.

Comment: Sounds great! What makes it inefficient?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means to "set a timer"?  Is that a visual count-down timer that basically just updates on some UI? Or do you need a service-side timer that is supposed to do something every hour and every minute from when started until stopped? For the former your solution seems fine but for the latter you'd probably want to take a look at step functions, or cloudwatch events to orchestrate the timer "tick" events

Comment: @MikeDinescu It's more of the latter. I want to update Dynamo after the 'start' of the timer and after 'end'. The timer counts up and tracks how many hours and minutes the user is in a certain state. After the timer 'ends' (this is triggered when the user scans a qr code) the timer updates dynamo with how many hours and minutes were in between 'start' and 'end'

Comment: it still sounds like the timer "ticking" functionality is external to Dynamo -- in which case the strategy you mention in the post seems fine